# outlook 2007 - only one folder not syncing with gmail imap

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, gmail-imap

Using Outlook 2007, windows xp, have my gmail imap setup and all is syncing fine, except one folder.  Outlook says only 53 unread, gmail have over 1000 unread.  unsubscribed and subscribed again - but still every other folder and subfolder syncs fine except for this one folder, and this folder is not syncing at all, even the unread messages!!!  Been like this for a few days already.

Comment: ok, sounds like a good idea.  It is a large folder so will take some time - will try to post an update soon...

Comment: It is working.  Taking a long time to update, but the strange thing is that outlook says about 5800 items in the folder and gmail says about 4700 items/emails.  Maybe when it finishes updating it will correct.  Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you unsubscribe, delete the folder in Outlook, then re-subscribe to it.